# Splitting multilinestrings in segments using PosgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, line, splitting, segment

I need to split several multilinestring into a defined number of segments using PosgreSQL.

I tried using `ST_subdvide`and `ST_segmentize` but they didn't work.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

I tried using the following SQL string to split the first line in segments of 2 m:

```
with x as(

select * from city.street t
where id_street = 1)

select 
id_street,
st_astext(geom),
st_astext(st_segmentize (x.geom, 2))from x;
```

Comment: http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/breaking-linestring-into-segments.html

Answer (score 1):

I could propose a function in postgreSQL as follows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.__bvv_segmentize_by(
    tabname text,
    geomname text,
    condition text,
    partnumber integer)
    RETURNS table(id integer, len double precision, segment geometry(linestring, 4326))
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    expr text;
    r record;
    pntnum integer;
    i integer;
    pnt_1 geometry;
    pnt_2 geometry;
    line_geom geometry;
    len double precision;
    delta double precision;
    accum_len double precision;
    threshold double precision;
BEGIN
    expr = 'select ST_LineMerge(%s) as geom from %s where %s limit 1';
    expr = format(expr, geomname, tabname, condition);
    raise notice 'expr=%', expr;
    threshold = 0.001;

    for r in execute expr
    loop
        line_geom = r.geom;
        len = ST_Length(line_geom);
        delta = 1.0 / partnumber;
        accum_len = 0;
        i = 0;
        loop
            pnt_1 = ST_LineInterpolatePoint(line_geom, accum_len);
            accum_len = accum_len + delta;
            if accum_len > 1.0 and (accum_len - 1.0) < threshold 
            then 
                accum_len = 1.0;
            end if;
            exit when accum_len > 1.0;
            pnt_2 = ST_LineInterpolatePoint(line_geom, accum_len);
            i = i + 1;
            return query select i, ST_Length(ST_MakeLine(pnt_1, pnt_2)),ST_MakeLine(pnt_1, pnt_2);
        end loop;
    end loop;
END

$BODY$;
```

If you create a table with a MultiLineString geometry field like

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_1
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    geom geometry(MultiLineString,3857),
    CONSTRAINT test_1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and draw a MultiLineString

then after performing the following query (the last parameter 6 is a number of segments)

```
select id, len, segment from __bvv_segmentize_by('test_1', 'geom', 'id=1', 6)
```

you will get the following table 
[image: The result table]

and the following map view where you will find your MultiLineString split into 6 parts

[image: Split line]